# prettier: SyntaxError: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed

Tags: code-formatting, prettier

I get this error when I run prettier.

```
..\index.component.html
[error] ..\index.component.html: SyntaxError: Only void and foreign elements can be self closed "home-hero" (3:5)
[error]   1 |
[error]   2 |   <layout>
[error] > 3 |     <home-hero slot="hero" />
[error]     |     ^
[error]   4 |
[error]   5 |     <h3 slot="callout" />
[error]   6 |
```

But I want to use self close tag. How set prettier to ignore this error?

In [prettier schema](http://json.schemastore.org/prettierrc) I don't see any reference of "self" or something like this.

Comment: Is this an angular/react/nativescript application?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a feature with `HTML` standard as mentioned in the below thread -

[Are (non-void) self-closing tags valid in HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-non-void-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5/3558200#3558200)

All the modern libraries `like` angular use the HTML5 standard for template in which case the user defined templates will be treated as `non-void` and hence you have to close the tag with proper ending tag.

Here is the complete list of HTML tag description related to `void` and `non-void`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element

You can also check the `spec` related to tech `home-hero` is written whether they allow the self closing tags!